# Integrate: $\int\limits_0^\infty{\frac{x^{n-2}}{b\left(1+ ~a x^{\frac{n-1}{n-2}}\right)} \sin{(x b)}~ dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{n-2} \over 
b\,\left(1 + ax^{\frac{n - 1}{n - 2}}\right)}\,\sin\left(bx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
\quad
\mbox{where}\ x \in \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{and}\ a, b, n\ \mbox{are positive real constants.}
$$

I have tried several things, including adding a complex phase and taking the vanishing limit and some substitutions, but I have not been successful so far. Mathematica is also confused by the integral.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this ?. Are there any obvious methods to solve this ( or even just write in terms of gamma functions or something workable ) that I have been overlooking ?.

Thanks !.

Comment: By using the substitution $t=\dfrac1{1+ax^m}$ and recognizing the expression of the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, followed by employing the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), we have: $$k=\frac nm\quad\iff\quad\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+ax^m}dx=\frac{\pi}{m\cdot a^k\cdot\sin k\pi}$$

Comment: @Lucian, could you please explain what happens to the sin term?

Comment: The two integrals aren't the same. (The reason I posted mine is because I thought that it might eventually be of *some* help to you or to others in evaluating the original, since they are both so similar).

Comment: Alright, I realized they weren't the same; but I thought you were saying they were somehow analogous. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this integral diverge?